# The flutter project cannot be run in release mode

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I opened a Flutter project in Xcode. I can use the emulator to run it in debug mode, but it won't run in release mode, nor will it be packaged. I can't find a specific error message. I don't know why. Can someone help me?

```
PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dxgaiocdvdjvonbkpwvrsyrlzgza/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    
  ...

    /bin/sh -c /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dxgaiocdvdjvonbkpwvrsyrlzgza/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Release-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh


Failed to package /Users/xxx/Desktop/WorkSpace/star_fission.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I removed Podfile.lock, Pods, and.xcworkspace and re-executed Pod install. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this
Go to

```
Keychain Access -> Right-click on login -> Lock & unlock again

Xcode -> Clean Xcode project ->Make build again
```

Comment: macOS 11.6.8. Right-click on login，I can't lock. Because this option can't be clicked.

Comment: I have solved the problem. I deleted the project and cloned it again to install the dependency.